# Cakephp error:Call to a member function find() on a non-object

Tags: php, cakephp-1.3

I am having problems with my code. When I try to debug my web application I get the following error message....Call to a member function find() on a non-object.....here is my code

class TeamsController extends AppController {

```
var $name = 'Teams';

function index() {
$this->set('teams', $this->team->find('all'));

}

function Welcome() {

}
```

}

I am trying to display records from my MySQL database. Now with that said, I did this tutorial and I followed the instructions down to the tee.....but somehow my code has bugs. The only difference between my code and the code of the tutorial I did is the variable names...and the controller names....and the I dont have the hello world function... Here is a sample of the code from the tutorial I did....

class PostsController extends AppController {

```
var $name = 'Posts';

function index() {
    $this->set('posts', $this->Post->find('all'));
}

function hello_world() {

}
```

}

With that said, am I suppose to declare an instance of an object to get this to work?

Answer (score 1):

It's likely a case sensitivity issue:

```
function index() {
    $this->set('teams', $this->Team->find('all'));
}
```

If not, ensure your controller has access to the *Teams* model (e.g. `$uses`).